# Call methods of new Android APIs in SDK version switch

Tags: android

The latest Android APIs have some helpful methods that are not available to older Android versions. The `DatePicker`, for example, has a new method called `setCalendarViewShown()` that is not available for old APIs such as Android 2.2 (level 8) and so on.

However, I've set the minimum API level to 8 and the target level to 16. So I would like to use these methods if available (on level 11+ devices).

Now I've tried to distinguish between several API levels programatically and, if available, call the method like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
}
```

Is this approach okay? In Eclipse, there's just some warnings, but they can be suppressed, of course. Due to checking for the `SDK_INT`, this code should be fine and cause no problems, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this approach okay?

I'd use `Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` instead of `11` for readability, but otherwise yes.

> In Eclipse, there's just some warnings, but they can be suppressed, of course.

Eclipse will point out that `setCalendarViewShown()` does not exist in API Level 8. It has no reliable means of confirming that you are only calling that method within a version guard block, so it just complains. Using the `TargetApi(11)` annotation will get rid of it, while still ensuring that if you add something *else* to the method that needs something higher than 11, you will get warned again.

> Due to checking for the SDK_INT, this code should be fine and cause no problems, shouldn't it?

Yes.

BTW, in this particular case, there's an XML attribute you could use (`android:calendarViewShown`) to replace the call. As XML attributes are automatically ignored on older versions, you could then skip the `Build` check.

Comment: Very late question, but at what point did it become OK to simply guard new API calls with an if or switch statement instead of using reflection to access the newer methods? Was this done at the compiler level, or does it require a minSdkVersion above a certain level? Thanks.

Comment: As seen here it used to be necessary to use reflection: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html?m=1

Comment: @Tenfour04: I believe Android 3.0's Dalvik started supporting this. IIRC, prior to that, the app would crash immediately upon loading a class that referred to unidentified symbols. With Android 3.0, Dalvik would wait to crash until you *used* those unidentified symbols. I'm not 100% on that timing, but IIRC it was 3.0.

Comment: Thank you. I've been having trouble finding any announcement of the change but this is a start. I didn't know if it was fixed in the compiler or the runtime.